# How to select multiple values from dynamic drop down box in php?

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I am trying to make a dynamic drop down menu from fetching the data from MySQL database, i wanted to implement multiple select from drop down ..would any any please help me out.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `multiple` attribute of HTML `<select>` to achieve this.

Here's a demo:

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Press `Ctrl`/`Cmd` to select multiple options.

Comment: Instead of ctrl/cmd , can i put check box inside drop down.

Comment: Choose Tags:
      <?php
       echo "<select name='new' multiple='multiple' size='10'>";
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
       echo "<option value='" . $row['tag_title'] ."'>" . $row['tag_title']."</option>";
      }
       echo "</select>";
     ?>                                                                                                                                This is how i am fetching data in to drop down from database, i want to select multiple values from  drop down. Is that right way of implementing.?

Comment: @ABBHI I think this plugin will be helpful for you: [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/). Checkout the demo on the same page in step 3. Note that it needs jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple>
```

add multiple in the select box

to select the multiple value you need to click and press controll  to select the  multiple option on the  select dropdown